# empathy and pidgin cannot connect to AIM

Tags: 11.10, empathy, pidgin

I'm on 11.10 and after an update last week I can no longer connect to AIM with Empathy or Pidgin. I can connect with Kopete so I know it's not the AIM account. I've tried deselecting "use clientLogin" in Pidgin and that made no difference. I've uninstalled and re-installed both Pidgin and Empathy but that made no difference. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes during updates but usually during upgrades, some things quit working. This is called a regression and should be reported as a bug.  [How to submit a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks. I usually assume user error when I have a problem ;) Guess I'll be submitting my first Ubuntu bug today.